# vuetify v-text-field background color changes after giving a value

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify to create a login form and I use v-text-field for the inputs.
The problem happens when there are suggestions for a field :

[image]

For example I have multiple emails saved in my browser, it will give me suggestions of these emails on an email field, all good so far.
But when I select one of them :

[image]

See the background color of the field went from white to light blue.

I hope there is a way to disable this behaviour because I have a dark background on my website and when the background changes it's very ugly.
I tried to find the element in the HTML and change the style but it doesn't take effect.

Comment: There is the codepen example https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Ffr-FR%2Fcomponents%2Ftext-fields%2F

Comment: please take a look that your codepen link is broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using Google Chrome (or another webkit-based browser). It comes from autocomplete feature in Chrome and not related to vuetify library.

You can fix this issue (at least in **Google Chrome 83**) using CSS.

If you want to manually **override background color**, you can overlap it by internal box-shadow. It makes no sense to set box-shadow's spread-radius to more than 30px (only if the size of your field is really huge):

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 30px #ffffff inset !important;
}
```

But if you want to make your input background **transparent**, you may set another CSS prop:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make it inherit the background of the parent div ? I have a gradient background so no defined color (instead of #fffffff)

Comment: @Roronoa_D._Law, yes it's possible. I've already update my answer

Comment: Well now I have black text on dark background

Comment: solved with -webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;