# Vuetify - Change autofill background color

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've been trying to change the background color of a text field in a form after autofill is used. The background color is set to black and the color is set to black but the autofill color is white.

[image: textfield]

I've tried using CSS to set the color like mentioned here and can't get it to change. It doesn't seem right that this happens either as I would have thought Vuetify would handle this for you without custom CSS.

[vuetify v-text-field background color changes after giving a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62796362/vuetify-v-text-field-background-color-changes-after-giving-a-value)

**v-text-field**

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="firstName"
  :rules="nameRules"
  label="First Name"
  required
  outlined
  background-color="black"
  color="black"
></v-text-field>
```

What is the correct method of setting the autofill background color?

Comment: Support on this is still pending in Vuetify: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5269

Comment: CSS can always change this color - you just need to create the correct (more specific) selector and eventually add `!important`